# Phasors with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This afternoon I was looking for a way to draw phasors with tikz (you know the thing which is represented in the complex plane as `r*exp(i \theta)` or simply `x + iy`)

For me, the first representation would be much easier to deal with.

Should I use the polar system simply ? But then it comes tricky to make vector summations...

Comment: Are you meaning something like an "A" followed by an angle symbol with the angle measure inside it? The one explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_notation

Comment: Do you just want to draw a vector? TikZ can everything in polar coordinates (including the `+(coordinate)` movement/addition operation).

Comment: @s__C Would you please better state what you need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The summation is not that tricky if you just use the regular polar form. Here is a simple starter:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3,2);

\coordinate (vec1) at (60:1); % Define some complex numbers
\coordinate (vec2) at (20:2); % with r*exp(i \theta) form

\draw[->,thick,blue] (0,0) -- (vec1);
\draw[->,thick,red] (0,0) -- (vec2);
\draw[dashed] (vec2) -- ++(vec1); % This how to add a vector to another
\draw[dashed] (vec1) -- ++(vec2); % using the coordinates as vectors
\draw[->,thick,orange] (0,0) -- ($(vec1) + (vec2)$); % This is how to do arithmetic
                                                     % operations on the coordinates.
                                                     % (requires calc library of TikZ.
                                                     % See the manual )
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: @s__C: If this answers you question you may accept it by clicking the gray checkmark below the vote buttons. This will bring some reputation to percusse and you.

Answer (score 9):

It is taken from [Phasor Diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/phasor-diagram/):

[image]

```
%& -shell-escape
% Phasor diagram
% Author: Urs Zellweger (urs@zellweger.li)
% GNUPLOT required
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title: Phasor diagram

\end{comment}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\usepgfmodule{plot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\newcommand{\Gitter}[4]{
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (#1,#3) grid (#2,#4);
}
\newcommand{\Koordinatenkreuz}[6]{
    \draw[->, >=latex, color=green!50!black] (#1,0) -- (#2,0) node[right] {#5};
    \draw[->, >=latex, color=green!50!black] (0,#3) -- (0,#4) node[left] {#6};
}
\newcommand{\KoordinatenkreuzOhneLabelsVerschobenKeinPfeil}[5]{
    \draw[-] (#1,0) -- (#2,0);
    \draw[-] (#5,#3) -- (#5,#4);

}
\newcommand{\ZeigerdiagrammText}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.72, samples=100, >=latex]

    \def\Alpha{#1}
    \def\Phase{#2}
    \def\AmplitudeSpannung{#3}
    \def\AmplitudeStrom{#4}
    \def\SpannungsWert{{\AmplitudeSpannung*sin(\Alpha)}}
    \def\StromWert{{\AmplitudeStrom*sin(\Alpha+\Phase)}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \def\FarbeSpannung{blue!90!white}
    \def\FarbeStrom{red!90!white}
    \def\FarbeWinkelZeichnung{green}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \def\Beta{\Alpha+\Phase}
    \def\AlphaRad{\Alpha*3.141592654/180}
    \def\PhaseRad{\Phase*3.141592654/180}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \Gitter{-.1}{7.1}{-3.1}{3.1}
    \Koordinatenkreuz{-.2}{7.3}{-3.2}{3.3}{$\omega t$}{}
    \draw (1.570795,0) node[below]{$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
    \draw (3.14159,0) node[below]{${\pi}$};
    \draw (4.71238898,0) node[below]{$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
    \draw (6.283185307,0) node[below]{${2\pi}$};
    \draw (-4,0) circle (3cm);
    \KoordinatenkreuzOhneLabelsVerschobenKeinPfeil{-7.2}{-.8}{-3.6}{3.6}{-4}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    % voltage
    \draw[color=\FarbeSpannung, very thick] plot[id=voltage, domain=0:7, smooth, variable=\x] ({\x},{\AmplitudeSpannung*sin(deg(\x))}) node[right] {$U(t)$};
    % voltage circle
    \draw[color=\FarbeSpannung, loosely dashed] (-4,0) circle (\AmplitudeSpannung cm);
    % angle
    \draw[color=\FarbeWinkelZeichnung!50!black, thick] (\AlphaRad, \SpannungsWert)--(\AlphaRad,\StromWert) node[below=18pt] {$\alpha$};
    % angle in the circle
    \filldraw[fill=\FarbeWinkelZeichnung!20,draw=\FarbeWinkelZeichnung!50!black] (-4,0) -- (-3,0) arc (0:\Alpha:1) -- cycle node[right] {$\alpha$};
    % voltage pointer
    \draw[<-,color=\FarbeSpannung, very thick] (\Alpha:\AmplitudeSpannung)++(-4,0) --(-4,0);
    \draw[color=\FarbeSpannung,  dashed] (\Alpha:\AmplitudeSpannung)++(-4,0) -- (\AlphaRad,\SpannungsWert);
    % current
    \draw[color=\FarbeStrom, very thick] plot[id=current, domain=0:7, smooth, variable=\x] ({\x},{\AmplitudeStrom*sin(deg(\x+\PhaseRad)}) node[right] {$I(t)$};     
    % current circle
    \draw[color=\FarbeStrom, loosely dashed]    (-4,0) circle (\AmplitudeStrom cm);
    % current pointer
    \draw[<-,color=\FarbeStrom, very thick] (\Beta:\AmplitudeStrom)++(-4,0) --(-4,0);
    \draw[color=\FarbeStrom,  dashed](\Beta:\AmplitudeStrom)++(-4,0) -- (\AlphaRad,\StromWert);
    % phase difference
    \ifthenelse{\Phase<0}{
        \draw[snake=brace] (pi/2 ,3.3)--(pi/2-\PhaseRad ,3.3) node[above=7pt, left=10pt] {$\phi$};
    }
    {
        \draw[snake=brace] (pi/2-\PhaseRad ,3.3)--(pi/2 ,3.3) node[above=7pt, left=10pt] {$\phi$};
    }
    % angular velocity \omega
    \draw[->, xshift=-4cm]  (120:2.4cm) arc (120:170:2) node[below] {$\omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
% usage: {alpha}{phasedifferenceUI}{voltage}{current}{Ualpha}{Ialpha}
% resistor
\ZeigerdiagrammText{60}{0}{2.7}{1.8}

\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are 3 variants: for complex numbers `a+bi`, `re^phi*i`(where *phi* is an angle in rad) and `re^phi*i` (where *phi* in an angle in deg). For the first you specify the origin, a, b and the draw style, for the others the origin, r, phi and the draw style:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newdimen\xorig
\newdimen\yorig

\newcommand{\sumphasor}[4]% origin, a, b, style; (for z=a+bi)
{   \path (#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xorig}{\yorig}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfirst}{\xorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfirst}{\yorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsecond}{\xorig/28.453+#2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysecond}{\yorig/28.453+#3}
  \draw[#4] (\xfirst,\yfirst) -- (\xsecond,\ysecond);
}

\newcommand{\expphasorpi}[4]% origin, r, phi(pi), style
{   \path (#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xorig}{\yorig}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfirst}{\xorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfirst}{\yorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsecond}{\xorig/28.453+#2*cos(#3/pi*180)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysecond}{\yorig/28.453+#2*sin(#3/pi*180)}
  \draw[#4] (\xfirst,\yfirst) -- (\xsecond,\ysecond);
}

\newcommand{\expphasordeg}[4]% origin, r, phi(pi), style
{   \path (#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xorig}{\yorig}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfirst}{\xorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfirst}{\yorig/28.453}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsecond}{\xorig/28.453+#2*cos(#3)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysecond}{\yorig/28.453+#2*sin(#3)}
  \draw[#4] (\xfirst,\yfirst) -- (\xsecond,\ysecond);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    {   \draw (-0.1,\x) -- (0.1,\x);
        \draw (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
    }
    \sumphasor{0,0}{3}{-2}{red,->,thick}
    \sumphasor{0,0}{1}{3}{blue,->,thick}
    \sumphasor{0,0}{4}{-0.3}{green,->,thick}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    {   \draw (-0.1,\x) -- (0.1,\x);
        \draw (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
    }
    \expphasorpi{0,0}{3}{0.785}{red,->,thick} % pi/4
    \expphasorpi{0,0}{2}{1.047}{blue,->,thick} % 1/3*pi
    \expphasorpi{0,0}{4}{-0.785}{green,->,thick} %-pi/4
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    {   \draw (-0.1,\x) -- (0.1,\x);
        \draw (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
    }
    \expphasordeg{0,0}{3}{-30}{red,->,thick} % pi/4
    \expphasordeg{0,0}{2}{75}{blue,->,thick} % 2/3*pi
    \expphasordeg{0,0}{4}{-45}{green,->,thick} %-pi/4
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    {   \draw (-0.1,\x) -- (0.1,\x);
        \draw (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
    }
    \sumphasor{0,0}{3}{-2}{red,-latex,thick}
    \sumphasor{0,0}{1}{3}{blue,-latex,thick}
    \sumphasor{3,-2}{1}{3}{densely dashed,thick}
    \sumphasor{1,3}{3}{-2}{densely dashed,thick}
    \sumphasor{0,0}{4}{1}{green!50!gray,-latex,thick}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One of the bases of tkz-elements is complex numbers. Points are more or less assimilated to their affixes. It's a little more complicated than that, because points, lines and circles are objects (in the sense of OOP object programming).

Objects have attributes such as modulus and argument for points. You don't need to calculate anything, as Lua does the calculation for you when you create the objects.

For plotting, you can use either Tikz, tkz-euclide. For tkz-euclide, I've just finished a "mini" version, meaning that only the plot macros are accessible.

I've given a few examples of how to use the `tkzUseLua` macro to retrieve values obtained with Lua.

I've added a little extra: multiplication of complexes; you can also divide them, take the conjugate, etc.

You need to compile with lualatex !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
   scale = 1
   z.O   = point : new ( 0 , 0 )
   z.I   = point : new ( 2 , 0 )
   z.v1  = point : polar ( 1 , math.pi/3 )
   z.v2  = point : polar ( 2 , math.pi/9 )
   z.V   = z.v1+z.v2
   z.P   = z.v1 * z.v2
\end{tkzelements}
   
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,gridded]
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawSegment[->,thick,blue](O,v1)
\tkzDrawSegment[->,thick,red](O,v2)
\tkzDrawSegment[->,thick,purple](O,V)
\tkzDrawSegment[->,thick,cyan](O,P)
\tkzDrawSegments[dashed](v1,V v2,V)
\tkzDrawArc[->](O,I)(P)
\tkzLabelArc[pos=.75,anchor = west](O,I,P){arg(v1)+arg(v2)=80°}
\end{tikzpicture}

\parindent=0pt
The modulus of V is \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.V.modulus,5)}\\
The argument of V is \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.V.argument,5)} rad either \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.V.argument /math.pi *180,5)}° .

v1 : \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.v1.re,5)} + \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.v1.im,5)} i\\
v2 : \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.v2.re,5)} + \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.v2.im,5)} i\\
V : \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.V.re,5)} + \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.V.im,5)} i\\
P : argument = \tkzUseLua{tkzround(z.P.argument /math.pi *180,5)}° .
\end{document}
```

[image]